# JavaScript regular expressions matching any alpha character with accents

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match any alpha character and any accented vowel - I'm using this regular expression

> [a-zA-Z\ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]+$

But unfortunately it only matches the last word in any string I provide for example:
[image]

If I add the ^ symbol to the start of the expression it only selects the first C

To clarify I am hoping to select multiple words but omit the whitespace that is found between them.  Is this possible?

Any advice most welcome.

L

[image]

Comment: You're not matching the space or whitespace (`\s`) character, so it can't match anything more than one word

Comment: Thank Shai - I don't want to match the whitespaces though  I just want the expression to find any characters?

Comment: Instead of *images* of text could you post some *real* text which features the characters you want to match? Also, could you show the output you expect from that string (or those strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from your comments, I understand that you simply want a global replacement for any of these `[a-zA-ZÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]` characters. Try this:

```
"Cúl do chinn".replace(/[a-zA-ZÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]/g, "-");
```

More info on the `/g` modifier on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (search for "global match" string in the document).

Comment: That was it - Thanks for bearing with me.  I didn't know how to ask the question but you were right - it is a global replacement.  Thank you I learned something

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
    \s*([a-zA-Z]*[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú][a-zA-Z]*)\s*
```

Regex with global option.

Screen in [http://gskinner.com/RegExr/]: http://coment.me/sTNE5RD

Comment: Thank for your response.  It still doesn't find all the characters for me though.  Maybe I'm not understanding how regex works properly.  What I'm hoping to select is all the letters 'cúl' 'do' 'chinn'  and then replace them with --- -- -----   I'm making a game that only provides blanks or dashes to the user instead of the letters.

Comment: so?     `"Cúl do chinn".replace(/[áéíóú]/, '-')`

Comment: No it's more like "Cúl do chinn".replace(/[a-zA-Z][áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ]/, '_');   but my problem is it's only finding either the 'chinn' or the 'C'

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help - I should have mentioned that it needed to be global.  I'm a complete beginner with regex - thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Then for completeness so:  `"Cúl do chinn".replace(/[a-záéíóú]/ig, "-");`